# Read 1 TB or greater size binary file using any Fastest reading method

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-mapped-files, file-read

I want to read 1 TB or greater size binary file using fastest reading method in c++.

I am trying file memory mapping and map a block of ((500 * 1024 * 1024)byte) size of the file sequentially and then read (every 32768 byte) from this block.
But it takes double time compared to if I use dynamic buffer to read and parse the file data.

System configuration:

- Processor: Intel(R)Core(TM) i5-2310 CPU @2.90GHz 2.90 Ghz
- RAM: 8 GB, OS: 64-bit,x64-based processor, windows10

I am using following code:

```
const unsigned int BlockSize = 500 * 1024 * 1024;
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(FilePath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, 0);
if(hFile)
{ ULARGE_INTEGER  uli; uli.LowPart = GetFileSize(hFile , &uli.HighPart);
LONGLONG FileSize = uli.QuadPart;       
HANDLE hFileMap = NULL; 
hFileMap = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
if (hFileMap !=NULL)
{
    unsigned __int64 iPos =0,iLeft=0,iBytesToRead;
    unsigned __int64 BlockSize = 500*1024*1024;
    unsigned __int64 curPos=0;
    while(iPos < FileSize)
    {
        iLeft = FileSize - iPos;
        iBytesToRead = iLeft > BlockSize ? BlockSize: iLeft;
        uli.QuadPart = iPos;    
        char* rawBuffer = (char*)MapViewOfFile(hFileMap, FILE_MAP_READ, uli.HighPart,uli.LowPart,iBytesToRead);
        if (!rawBuffer) {
          curPos=0;
          while((curPos < iBytesToRead){
            curPos += 32768;
          }
          UnmapViewOfFile(rawBuffer);
        }
        iPos += iBytesToRead ;
      }
      CloseHandle(hFileMap);
    }
    CloseHandle(hFile);
```

1. First I want to know that is file memory mapping the fastest way to read a binary file?
2. If it is the fastest method then why it take double the time?
3. How can I improve the above code to get maximum reading speed?
4. In `MapViewOfFile()` function, how much `NumberOfBytes` can I map if file size is greater than available RAM?
5. Already tried above method using multithread but no speed gain.
6. If there is any other fastest method to read a binary file (1 TB or greater size), please tell me.

Comment: Just to clarify, with 'reading' you mean just copying all the file data in RAM?

Comment: The most important hardware information is missing: the storage device. Besides this, memory-mapped files are not always necessary faster than the usual libc approach, especially with your code that makes a lot of system call to `MapViewOfFile`/`UnmapViewOfFile`. Using parallelism can strongly help or also decrease performance regarding the storage device (and the OS which is apparently Windows here). Parallel reads are generally faster with many modern SSD but not HDD. 1TB is a lot. Consider using compression and a bigger chunk size and ensure you use a SSD.

Comment: Hi @MatG I want to read each page (Page Size 32768 byte) header information of 1 TB or greater Size with any Fastest reading method. Currently I open and read file data in a dynamic buffer (Buffer size depend on available RAM) and read page header from this buffer. But this process take time in hours to read 1 TB file. I want to read this file in minutes.

Comment: Hi @Richard please tell me In MapViewOfFile() function, Can I map NumberOfBytes (last parameter of MapViewOfFile()) greater than available RAM? So I could decrease the lot of system call to MapViewOfFile/UnmapViewOfFile. I am using HDD not SSD. I also try after taking big dynamic buffer( In GB) but instead of decreasing it increase file reading time. Can you explain any approach or method to read this file in minutes not in hours